# The second image is playing the same sound as the first image in html

Tags: html

so i am new to `html5` so this question might be stupid but i am trying  to make images make diffrent  sounds when clicked, here is my code:

```
<audio id="audio_play">
    <source src="<https://www.fesliyanstudios.com/play-mp3/6560>" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>

<img src="<https://www.thesprucepets.com/thmb/KYaXBSM013GnZ2jEZJnX4a9oIsU=/3865x2174/smart/filters:no_upscale()/horse-galloping-in-grass-688899769-587673275f9b584db3a44cdf.jpg>" style="width:156px;height:96px;" onClick="document.getElementById('audio_play').play(); return false;" />


<audio id="audio_play">
    <source src="<https://www.fesliyanstudios.com/play-mp3/6520>" type="audio/mpeg" />

</audio>
<img src="<https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fthumb%2F2%2F2d%2FHinterwald_Cattle_Hinterzarten.jpg%2F1200px-Hinterwald_Cattle_Hinterzarten.jpg&f=1&nofb=1>" style="width:100px;height:100px;" onClick="document.getElementById('audio_play').play(); return false;" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of your `audio` elements have the same `id`, [which is not valid HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) because `id` attributes "must be unique in the whole document". You should rename the second to something like `<audio id="audio_play2">`, and then adjust the second image to be `onClick="document.getElementById('audio_play2').play(); return false;"` to reference that audio element instead.

Additionally, you have `<source src="<https://www.fesliyanstudios.com/play-mp3/6560>"` where `<` and `>` shouldn't be included, as well as removing those characters from the `src` attribute on the image tags.

Your HTML should be like this (indented for readability):

```
<audio id="audio_play">
    <source
        src="https://www.fesliyanstudios.com/play-mp3/6560" 
        type="audio/mpeg"
    />
</audio>

<img
src="https://www.thesprucepets.com/thmb/KYaXBSM013GnZ2jEZJnX4a9oIsU=/3865x2174/smart/filters:no_upscale()/horse-galloping-in-grass-688899769-587673275f9b584db3a44cdf.jpg"
    style="width:156px;height:96px;" 
    onClick="document.getElementById('audio_play').play(); return false;" />


<audio id="audio_play2">
    <source
        src="https://www.fesliyanstudios.com/play-mp3/6520" 
        type="audio/mpeg"
    />
</audio>
<img
src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fthumb%2F2%2F2d%2FHinterwald_Cattle_Hinterzarten.jpg%2F1200px-Hinterwald_Cattle_Hinterzarten.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" 
    style="width:100px;height:100px;" 
    onClick="document.getElementById('audio_play2').play(); return false;" />
```

But if you have many of these image/audio pairs on the page, it's cleaner abstract the HTML/JS by wrapping the pairs in a div and then using class and element selectors to reference the correct audio file instead of adjusting each img's `onClick` value. You can use an [event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick) to automatically link all of your images to their relevant audio element like this:

```js
let wrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.image_audio_wrapper');
wrappers.forEach(function(wrapper) {
    let img = wrapper.querySelector('img');
    
    img.addEventListener('click', function() {
        let audio = this.parentElement.querySelector('audio');
        audio.play();
        
        console.log('playing audio file: ' + audio.querySelector('source').src);
    }, false);
});
```

```html
<div class="image_audio_wrapper">
  <audio>
        <source
            src="https://www.fesliyanstudios.com/play-mp3/6560" 
            type="audio/mpeg"
        />
    </audio>
  <img src="https://www.thesprucepets.com/thmb/KYaXBSM013GnZ2jEZJnX4a9oIsU=/3865x2174/smart/filters:no_upscale()/horse-galloping-in-grass-688899769-587673275f9b584db3a44cdf.jpg" style="width:156px;height:96px;" />
</div>

<div class="image_audio_wrapper">
  <audio>
        <source
            src="https://www.fesliyanstudios.com/play-mp3/6520" 
            type="audio/mpeg"
        />
    </audio>
  <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fthumb%2F2%2F2d%2FHinterwald_Cattle_Hinterzarten.jpg%2F1200px-Hinterwald_Cattle_Hinterzarten.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" style="width:100px;height:100px;"
  />
</div>
```